# Do optimizers move temporary non-POD types out of loops?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction

Given the following code:

```
while(is_running)
{
     std::vector<buffer> buffers;

     // fill buffers

     // use buffers
}
```

Does modern compilers perform the following transformation?

```
std::vector<bufer> buffers;

while(is_running)
{
     // fill buffers

     // use buffers

     buffers.clear();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the second one would be more efficient? Did you profile?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The only reason I can think of is that the first version has to have an allocation/de-allocation per loop cycle, the second one not necessarily so.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Correct, the second one will not unecessarily allocate/deallocate during each loop iteration.

Comment: Why would you want to rely on unknown optmizing behaviour oif you know that the code does what you need if you do the change yourself and is more clear this way?

Comment: @Devolus probably because the clearer version (the first one) is *potentially* the less efficient one. So there is a trade-off between clarity and efficiency (of course, one has to measure first to see if it makes a difference, as always).

Comment: @juanchopanza: As you said, but I'm also curious about how smart compilers are.

Comment: @juanchopanza, the question is wether you should rely on some particular optimization tricks, which can change on criterias you don't have nmuch influcene on. If this is not a critical section, then it shouldn't matter, otherwise you probably would want to have something more reliable then just betting on the optimizer. And you are right, you have to measure it anyway.

Comment: @Devolus: One of the reasons I'm asking is to know whether this is an obvious optimization, such as NRVO etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to know with certainty would be to test, *but* I would be rather surprised to see an optimizer carry out this optimization.

To even begin to carry out this optimization, the compiler would have to either 1) know enough about the internals of the functions involved to "realize" (for example) that `operator new` and `operator delete` are basically mirror images of either other, or 2) it would have to generate *all* the code for all the functions inline (all the way down to the invocations of `operator new` and `operator delete`, and have enough intelligence to be able to deduce the same conclusion from the code.

I can barely imagine the first, but don't recall having ever seen it. Given the complexities of a typical heap manager, the second strikes me as truly unbelievable.

Bottom line: I've been surprised before, and I'm sure I will be again -- but but would be a bigger surprise than most.

Comment: Also, the compiler would have to worry about the side-effects of, for example, global variables - including for example `errno`.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised to see that the compiler actually knows the std containers and invokes their methods without my explicit request. If that was the case, imagine how the compiler's logic would need to be augmented whenever a new library module was released!

It would be interesting, though, to find out that some C++ compilers do have some knowledge of the Standard Library.

EDIT: Ok, I found an example of such knowledge: the C++11 range-based for loops apply std::begin and std::end to ranges.

Anyway, it is us programmers who have to really understand what the code we write does and figure out ways to optimize it. The compiler should simply translate our instructions applying only small (but significant) optimizations (like inlining, copy elision etc.)